# Web Scraping contents of ::before ::after CSS Psuedo element using BeautifulSoup

Tags: css, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm learning Web Scraping. I would like to know how can we fetch participants count from below element?

```
<li class="header-hero__stat header-hero__stat--participants">
   ::before
   "255,590 Participants"
   ::after
</li>
```

Code I've tried

```
soupy = bs(html,'lxml') 
ul = soupy.find('li',{'class':"header-hero__stats"})
```

returns `None`

[Target page](https://www.datacamp.com/courses/intermediate-python-for-data-science)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not content of pseudo-elements, but text content of `li` node, so

```
li = soup.find('li',{'class':"header-hero__stat--participants"}).text
```

should be enough to extract `'255,601 Participants'`

Use `.text.split()[0]` to get number only

Comment: Thanks buddy! Could you telle why below code returned None object then?     
    `soupy=bs(html,'lxml')
    ul=soupy.find('li',{'class':"header-hero__stats"})`

Comment: This data might be generated dynamically by JavaScript, so you might need to wait some time. Can you share exact code you've tried?

Comment: @MasooriMenon , sorry, for some reason I thought that you're using Selenium :) So provided solution is related to Selenium... That data probably comes from XHR, so you need to simulate proper call to API. Can you share URL of target page?

Comment: `https://www.datacamp.com/courses/intermediate-python-for-data-science` is link and I'm using bs4. Thanks again!

Comment: @MasooriMenon , its very simple, your using wrong selector. Try either `ul=soup.find('ul',{'class':"header-hero__stats"})` to locate `ul` node or `li=soup.find('li',{'class':"header-hero__stat--participants"})` to locate target `li` node