# how to remove list brackets from the web scraped data

Tags: python, web-scraping, web, beautifulsoup

i'm trying to scrape some data from a website but the final result have the output data in lists, so how can i extract the data without those list brackets.

[image]

**The Original Code:-**

```
user_input =  'ios-phones'#input('Please Enter Your Favorite Item:- ')
try:
    data_list = []
    for i in range(1,30):

        url = f'https://www.jumia.com.eg/{user_input}/?page={i}#catalog-listing'
        page = requests.get(url).content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'lxml')
        phones = soup.find('div',class_='-paxs row _no-g _4cl-3cm-shs')
        phones_info = phones.find_all('article',class_=True)

        for i in phones_info:
            try:
                title = i.select('.name')[0].text.strip()
                current_price = i.select('.prc')[0].text
                old_price = i.find('div',class_='old')
                rating = i.find('div',class_='stars')
            except:
                pass

            row = {'Phone Title':title,'Current Price':current_price,'Old Price':old_price,'Rating':rating}
            data_list.append(row)
except:
    pass
df = pd.DataFrame(data_list)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main issue here seems to be that you append the bs4 objects for `old_price` and `rating` not its texts as you do with the first two `title` and `current_price` - So change to:

```
for i in phones_info:
    title = i.select_one('.name').get_text(strip=True)
    current_price = i.select_one('.prc').get_text(strip=True)
    old_price = i.select_one('.old').get_text(strip=True) if i.select_one('.old') else None
    rating = i.select_one('.stars').get_text(strip=True) if i.select_one('.stars') else None

    row = {'Phone Title':title,'Current Price':current_price,'Old Price':old_price,'Rating':rating}
    data_list.append(row)
```

##### Output

|  | Phone Title | Current Price | Old Price | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Apple Iphone 14 Pro Max – 5G Single SIM – 256/6GB RAM – Deep Purple | EGP 54,499.00 | EGP 70,000.00 | None |
| 1 | Apple IPhone 13 Single SIM With FaceTime - 128GB - Pink | EGP 29,999.00 | EGP 50,000.00 | 5 out of 5 |
| 2 | Apple IPhone 13 Pro Max Single SIM With FaceTime - 512GB - AlpineGreen | EGP 55,499.00 | EGP 65,000.00 | None |
| 3 | Apple IPhone 12 Mini With FaceTime - 128GB - Blue | EGP 25,900.00 | None | 4.7 out of 5 |
| 4 | Apple IPhone 12 With FaceTime - 128GB - Purple | EGP 27,900.00 | None | 4.2 out of 5 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |
| 35 | Apple Iphone 13 128G Green | EGP 31,900.00 | None | None |
| 36 | Apple IPhone 13 / 512GB / Pink | EGP 40,900.00 | None | None |
| 37 | Apple IPhone 13 (128GB) Red | EGP 31,900.00 | None | None |
| 38 | Apple IPhone 13 Pro Single SIM With FaceTime - 128GB - Sierra Blue | EGP 41,900.00 | None | None |
| 39 | Apple IPhone 13 128GB Starlight | EGP 31,900.00 | None | None |

Comment: i tried that but the output not accurate and the None rows take the same value for the pervious row, please check the old_ price and rating output again

Comment: Focus of OP is *how can i extract the data without those list brackets* and that is the solution for - If you check the source of the page you will see that you get what you are searching for, still if it is not visible rendered to the screen.

Comment: the issue in the above table for example is in index 3 & 4, the old price for them should be None and you can make sure from that in the original page, but the soultion that you have provided take the value of index 2 and repeat in in index 3 then the same matter happened in index 4

Comment: Depends on how it is accessed, get different information depending on the point. Maybe next time you could provide some example structure. Anyway, the revision should correspond to both the OP and the annotation.

Comment: Many thanks for your support, your last soultion has been working for me..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.sub` to subsitute the brackets in the string for blanks as such:

```py
import re

old_price = re.sub("\[|\]", "", old_price)
rating = re.sub("\[|\]", "", rating)
```

Sample input:

```py
old_price = "[EGP 50,000.00]"
rating = "[5 out of 5, []]"
```

Output:

```py
EGP 50,000.00
5 out of 5,
```

Comment: could you share your answer in my full code as i tried your solution but it didn't work with me

Comment: Where in your code did you implement it?

Comment: above in my original question you will find my original code

Comment: I mean where did you implement the _solution_. Is it after first getting the values, e.g. right above the `except` clause?

Comment: `title = i.select('.name')[0].text.strip()
current_price = i.select('.prc')[0].text
old_price = i.find('div',class_='old')
old_price = re.sub("\[|\]", "", old_price)
rating = i.find('div',class_='stars')
rating = re.sub("\[|\]", "", rating)`

Comment: And you also imported `re`?

Comment: yes, of course, imported it in my libararies

Comment: Could you check what the types of `old_price` and `rating` are?

Comment: <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 46 entries, 0 to 45
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------         --------------  ----- 
 0   Phone Title    46 non-null     object
 1   Current Price  46 non-null     object
 2   Old Price      23 non-null     object
 3   Rating         0 non-null      object
dtypes: object(4)

Comment: I think you could try using `old_price.string` and `rating.string` in the `re.sub` expression to get the text.

Comment: solved for the "old_price" but the "rating" not solved yet

Comment: It would be extremely helpful to get a snippet of what the actual page data looks like.

Comment: you can enter on that page(https://www.jumia.com.eg/ios-phones/)

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your code using the part you've provided. Anyway, maybe `.text` would work, since the element contains `::before`. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52936783/17200348).